# Switching Doctrine Entity in Zend Framework 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, annotations, zend-framework2, database-schema

I have two modules. 1) User Module and 2) RbacUser Module. RbacUser Module is depended on User Module. I extend my "User entity" from User Module in RbacUser Module and add some new attributes to User Entity like roles etc.

What i am to do is, When i used RbacUser Module, **make RbacUser Module User Entity default**. So schema tool know that which entity should use to create table ?

In Short Words:

if Only **User** Module is used then make its User Entity Default

or

if **RbacUser** Module is used then make its **User Entity** Default and ignore User's entity.

---

***I found the solution***

These are the configuration of my both modules

User Module Config file

```
User\Config\module.config.php
'driver' => array(
        'user_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(
                __DIR__.'/../src/User/Entity',
            ),
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                'User\Entity\User' => 'user_driver'
            )
        )
    ),
```

RbacUser Module config file

```
RbacUser\Config\module.config.php
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        'rbacuser_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\Driver\\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(
                __DIR__.'/../src/RbacUser/Entity',
            ),
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                'RbacUser\Entity\User' => 'rbacuser_driver'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

If i don't use "User" Module doctrine driver config then my problem is solved. **Is their any way to check if RbacUser Module is used then don't use doctrine driver configuration in "User" Module**

Comment: "Is their any way to check if RbacUser Module is used then don't use doctrine driver configuration in "User" Module" : you could check if the key $config['doctrine']['driver']['rbacuser_driver'] exists in the config service.

Comment: yes i can do this. But when i run command from cli to update my schema like this, doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --force then this command display error that user table already exist.

Comment: one solution i find is that, if $config['doctrine']['driver']['rbacuser_driver'] key exist then Read the User\Config\module.config.php configuration file through \zend\config\config and modify the configuration and write back to User\Config\module.config.php file through zend\config\writer . Is this methodology is correct or any other methodolgy should be adopted. My primary reason is to make module reusable so i can drop this module in my application and just update schema thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement an IdentityProvider in your RbacUser module and specify [this configuration key](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac/blob/master/config/zfc_rbac.global.php.dist#L31)

Comment: that is not the problem. the problem is, using two same entities is.1) "User" Entity in user Module and 2) "User" Entity which is extended by User Module in RbacUser Module. i found my problem and edited my problem. Please see "I found the solution" section of my post

Comment: So you want to use ```Tariq\Entity\User``` if ZfcRbac is not enabled, and ```Rbac\Entity\User``` if it is enabled ? You could use your entity as a service and then overwrite its definition  in the zfcrbac services config file.